# WPF: get TextRange from ListItem content

Tags: wpf, flowdocument, textrange

I am trying to get a TextRange from a WPF FlowDocument ListItem:

```
var doc = new FlowDocument();
doc.Blocks.Add(new List(new ListItem(new Paragraph(new Run("first bullet")))));
```

If I now try to get a TextRange with

```
var range1 = new TextRange(doc.ContentStart, doc.ContentEnd);
```

or

```
var range2 = new TextRange(doc.ContentStart.GetNextInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward), doc.ContentEnd);
```

I get a range where the Text property returns

```
•   first bullet
```

And if I try

```
var range3 = new TextRange(doc.ContentStart.GetNextInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward).GetNextInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward), doc.ContentEnd);
```

the Text property returns

```
irst bullet
```

The debugger shows:

```
range1.Start.Offset == 4
range2.Start.Offset == 4
range3.Start.Offset == 5
```

How could I create a TextRange which points to "first bullet" only (without the bullet and the separating tab)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is not in TextRange itself (*range1* points exactly to the text you need), but rather in its Text property. Let's refer to the implementation of [ITextRange.Text](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Documents/TextRange.cs,383).

It calls [GetText(ITextRange thisRange)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Documents/TextRangeBase.cs,f3a82223cd36937d) from TextRangeBase internal class, that **intentionally** moves starting TextPoiner backwards to **include initial list marker (if any)** and after that calls [GetTextInternal(ITextPointer startPosition, ITextPointer endPosition)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Documents/TextRangeBase.cs,99b67a7497b557c6)  with updated starting TextPointer.

This behavior can be reproduced with reflection:

```
var textRangeBase  = typeof(TextRange).Assembly.GetType("System.Windows.Documents.TextRangeBase");
var getTextInternal = textRangeBase.GetMethod("GetTextInternal"
    , BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static, null
    , new Type[] { typeof (TextPointer), typeof(TextPointer) }, null);

var text1 = getTextInternal.Invoke(null, new[] { range1.Start, range1.End });

var text2 = getTextInternal.Invoke(null, new[] { range1.Start
    .GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Backward)
    .GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Backward)
    .GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Backward)
    , range1.End });


//Results:
//text1: "first bullet\r\n"    
//text2: "•\tfirst bullet\r\n"
```

Comment: I published a repro here: https://github.com/plainionist/DevNull/tree/master/src/TextRangeFromListItem

it works exactly as u have described it - unfort. :'( ... so looks like I have to go for reflection hoping that the WPF guys do that change that api (so often).

Comment: Agree, implementation of GetText method is rather odd, probably they'll change that behavior in subsequent versions, who knows.